# Generating gmail oauth tokens - xoauth.py in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, gmail, imap

I am wondering if anyone knows of a ruby version of [Google's example python code (xoauth.py)](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough) to generate consumer oauth tokens?  Preferably something that will connect well with [gmail_xoauth](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth) or [gMail for Ruby](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail).

I've searched around a good amount and found some similar Stackoverflow questions in the past which don't give a clear enough answer unfortunately (eg: [How to implement Gmail IMAP with Omniauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084701/how-to-implement-gmail-imap-with-omniauth), [Rails app, gmail gem, xoauth: How to grant access to a specific application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415421/rails-app-gmail-gem-xoauth-how-to-grant-access-to-a-specific-application), [How do I connect to Gmail's IMAP server using oauth in Rails3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763168/how-do-i-use-connect-to-gmails-imap-server-using-oauth-in-rails3))

Thanks!

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843761/google-oauth-access-tokens/18452141#18452141

Answer (score 1):

I translated the Python code into Ruby to solve this. The details are in the following blog post.
http://blog.asif.in/blog/2012/03/03/google-oauth-and-rails/