# Google OAuth access tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap

I'm so confused by OAuth and Google. It took me forever to get the refresh_token to create a new access_token. Then to find out the refresh_token expires too?? What is the point of that!!!??

All I need to do is persist a valid access_token for use with [legato](https://github.com/tpitale/legato).

Here is what I manually enter into my terminal to retrieve an OAUTH code:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('GA_CLIENT_ID', 'GA_SECRET_KEY', {
        :authorize_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        :token_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
})
client.auth_code.authorize_url({
       :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
       :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost',
       :access_type => 'offline',
       :approval_prompt=> 'force'
})
```

Then I manually enter the outputted url to in my browser. I export the returned OAUTH code as to an env variable and get the access token:

```
access_token = client.auth_code.get_token(ENV['GA_OAUTH_CODE'], :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost')
```

Then I can access the access_token and refresh_token:

```
   begin
      api_client_obj = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['GA_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GA_SECRET_KEY'], {:site => 'https://www.googleapis.com'})
      api_access_token_obj = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(api_client_obj, ENV['GA_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN'])
      self.user = Legato::User.new(api_access_token_obj)
      self.user.web_properties.first # this tests the access code and throws an exception if invalid
    rescue Exception => e
      refresh_token
    end

  end

  def refresh_token
    refresh_client_obj =  OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['GA_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GA_SECRET_KEY'], {
            :authorize_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            :token_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
        })
    refresh_access_token_obj = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(refresh_client_obj, ENV['GA_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN'], {refresh_token: ENV['GA_OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN']})
    refresh_access_token_obj.refresh!
    self.user = Legato::User.new(refresh_access_token_obj)
  end
```

After an hour, my tokens expire and I have to manually start the process over again from the browser! How can I replicate this in code??

Comment: I don't suppose you've found an answer yet.  I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: No I haven't, but I believe the solution involves using the callback. I opened a more specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864199/how-to-configure-route-for-oauth-callback/16923267?noredirect=1#16923267. I haven't had a chance to try out the submitted answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, made a little something just for you :)

It's a simple implementation, specifically to ease the pain of renewing tokens.

Just be sure to:

1. Put in your own `APP_ID` and `APP_SECRET`.
2. Either only save your `refresh_token` and call `refresh_token()` every time before you use it, or use `refresh_token_if_needed()` every time, and re-save the `token` and `expires_at` (preferred obviously , since you'll only refresh when needed).
3. Let me know how it worked out.

.

```
require 'gmail'
require 'gmail_xoauth'
require 'httparty'

class GmailManager
  APP_ID      = "DDDDDDDDDDDD-SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  APP_SECRET  = "SSSSSS-SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS"

  def refresh_token(refresh_token)
    Rails.logger.info "[GmailManager:refresh_token] refreshing using this refresh_token: #{refresh_token}"
    # Refresh auth token from google_oauth2 and then requeue the job.
    options = {
      body: {
        client_id:     APP_ID,
        client_secret: APP_SECRET,
        refresh_token: refresh_token,
        grant_type:    'refresh_token'
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }
    response = HTTParty.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', options)
    if response.code == 200
      token = response.parsed_response['access_token']
      expires_in = DateTime.now + response.parsed_response['expires_in'].seconds
      Rails.logger.info "Success! token: #{token}, expires_in #{expires_in}"
      return token, expires_in
    else
      Rails.logger.error "Unable to refresh google_oauth2 authentication token."
      Rails.logger.error "Refresh token response body: #{response.body}"
    end
    return nil, nil
  end

  def refresh_token_if_needed(token, expires_on, refresh_token)
    if token.nil? or expires_on.nil? or Time.now >= expires_on
      Rails.logger.info "[GmailManager:refresh_token_if_needed] refreshing using this refresh_token: #{refresh_token}"
      new_token, new_expires_on = self.refresh_token(refresh_token)
      if !new_token.nil? and !new_expires_on.nil?
        return new_token, new_expires_on
      end
    else
      Rails.logger.info "[GmailManager:refresh_token_if_needed] not refreshing. using this token: #{token}"
    end
    return token, expires_on
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I took your code and made a nice class out of it: https://gist.github.com/Overbryd/0ae6287b02a9848e5b67