# How to configure route for oauth callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the gem [OAuth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) to communicate with Google services. I don't understand how to implement a callback, which receives the response with the OAuth code to get an access token. When I set a breakpoint in the `callback` method, it never seems to get called.

Here is my code:

Routes:

```
match '/oauth2/callback' => 'reports#callback'
```

Actual redirected url:

```
http://localhost/oauth2/callback?code=111111
```

ReportsController:

```
def new
 client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['GA_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GA_SECRET_KEY'], {
         :authorize_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
         :token_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    })
redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url({
        :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost/oauth2/callback',
        :access_type => 'offline'
    }) 
end

def callback
  oauth_code = params[:code]

  # Create access token with oauth_code
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google server is trying to access this url `http://localhost/oauth2/callback?code=111111` which is not valid.

You need a domain name to use a service like OAuth, because the google server must be able to find your computer over the internet.

To be able to do this from your development machine you should:

1. **Set a name on a known DNS server:** The easiest way to do this is through a Dynamic DNS server like [dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/) or [no-ip](http://www.noip.com/)
2. **If you are behind a router using `NAT`, you might need to redirect the requests to your modem on port 80 to your computer**: If you don't do this, your modem will receive a package on port 80 from google and will say "not for me", discarding it. You can do this in your modem menu - look for port forwarding or NAT section on it.

Comment: This makes sense, but when I change my redirect url to `http://SITE_NAME/oauth2/callback` and test in my production env, the callback is never fired. I made sure to use my production client_id and secret from google api console, as well as match the redirect url. I even add `approval_prompt => 'force'`

Comment: @mnort9 and yet have nothing on your production log, like something that could not be routed? Two things might be happening: 1) Google is not sending any request to you or 2) it is sending an wrong request and it is getting a routing error. I suggest also try to load the console on production and try the OAuth calls manually to see if you can find something wrong.

Comment: Ok I got this working in production. I will test your method locally as soon as I can.

Comment: great that worked. Other option, a little less reliable, is to mock google calls in your machine.

Comment: Can I somehow use my production callback locally?

Comment: @mnort9 No, because then google would always respond to the same machine and instance of rails, and you most likely want to keep your dev environment apart from the production. The most closely thing I can imagine is run the development in the same machine that are the production but in a different port (and so, the callback would be differente), or configure another domain (for example, dev.mysite.com) and [redirect the calls to your dynamic dns address](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/redirex/)

Comment: I got it working locally using `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` as the callback url. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you don't mind, please take a look at my other question. thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969881/rails-service-oauth-code-structure

Answer (score 1):

The redirect_url passed to google must match exactly the callback url as seen from client's browser. No problem to use localhost in the url (fotanus sentence about DNS and NAT is wrong). If you are running your container in a different port (e.g. 8080) you have to:

- Specify the url in google cloud: `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback`
- Specify that same return url in the client request.