# Rails service + oauth code structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble structuring the logic of OAuth integration into my web app. In the app, a user creates a Report that consists of data from their google analytics account.

User steps:

1. User clicks 'New Report'
2. Google presents the 'Allow Access' page for OAuth access
3. User is presented with a list of their GA web properties and selects one
4. A report is created using data from the selected web property

My issue is in structuring the code below.

When the user clicks "New Report", they are actually redirected to `google_analytics#ga_session` to begin the authorization process. The code to retrieve the user's web properties succeeds, but the code at the bottom needs to be refactored so it is reusable when retrieving web property data. The main two issues I can't figure out is how to make the GoogleAnalytics instance reusable and how to structure the oauth redirects.

**Retrieve web properties:**

GoogleAnalyticsController

```
def ga_session
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['GA_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GA_SECRET_KEY'], {
        :authorize_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        :token_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    })
    redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url({
         :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
         :redirect_uri => ENV['GA_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL'],
         :access_type => 'offline'
     })
  end

  def oauth_callback
    session[:oauth_code] = params[:code]
    redirect_to new_report_path
  end
```

ReportsController

```
def new
     @report = Report.new
     ga_obj = GoogleAnalytics.new
     ga_obj.initialize_ga_session(session[:oauth_code])
     @ga_web_properties = ga_obj.fetch_web_properties
end
```

GoogleAnalytics model

```
def initialize_ga_session(oauth_code)
    client = OAuth2::Client.new(ENV['GA_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GA_SECRET_KEY'], {
        :authorize_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        :token_url => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    })
    access_token_obj = client.auth_code.get_token(oauth_code, :redirect_uri => ENV['GA_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL'])
    self.user = Legato::User.new(access_token_obj)
  end

  def fetch_web_properties
    self.user.web_properties
  end
```

**Retrieve web property data:** when creating the report

ReportsController

```
def create
    @report = Report.new(params[:report])
    @report.get_top_traffic_keywords(session[:oauth_code])
    create!
end
```

Report Model

```
def get_keywords(oauth_code)
    ga = GoogleAnalytics.new
    ga.initialize_ga_session(oauth_code) # this is a problem b/c the user will be redirected the new_report_path after the callack
    self.url = ga.fetch_url(self.web_property_id)
    self.keywords = # Get keywords for self.url from another service
    keyword_revenue_data(oauth_code)
end

def keyword_revenue_data(oauth_code)
    ga = GoogleAnalytics.new
    ga.initialize_ga_session(oauth_code)
    revenue_data = # Get revenue data
end
```

Comment: This question actually belongs to [codeview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)